# Modifying PL/pgSQL function using generate_series()

Tags: sql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, generate-series, postgresql-8.3

I am working on a version of PostgreSQL 8.3 that does not support the variant of the `generate_series()` functions for date/time series. I have this ugly workaround at the moment that calls the function with a third argument like:

```
select table_union('2012-12-01', '2013-02-20', 79)
```

I have to compute the last parameter manually to determine the number of days for`generate_series()`.

What is the best way to modify this script so that I only need two arguments in the function call?

Is there a way to modify the below code to work the same way only given two arguments to the function like this?

```
select table_union('2012-12-01', '2013-02-20')
```

```
create or replace function table_union(date_from date, date_to date, numday int)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare
    day_1 date;
    _stop_ bigint := (date_from::date - date_to::date)::int; 
begin
    for day_1 in 
        select date_from + s.a as dates from generate_series(0, $3 ) as s(a)
    loop
        execute 'insert into dhcp.dhcp_map select * from dhcp.final_map_'|| trim( leading ' ' from to_char(extract(month from day_1), '09')) ||'_'|| 
        trim( leading ' ' from to_char(extract(day from day_1), '09'));  --to_char introduces a leadin space use trim to remove
    end loop;
end; $$;
```

Update:  I tried modifying my code after the great suggestions in the answer below but still have some errors:

```
create or replace function 
table_union(date_from date, date_to date) 
returns void language plpgsql 
as $func$ 
declare day_1 date; 
begin 
for day_1 in select date_from
 + s.a as dates from generate_series(0, (date_to - date_from)) 
as s(a) 
loop 
execute 
'insert into dhcp.dhcp_map select * from dhcp.final_map_'||
 array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT to_char(date_from + generate_series(0, (date_to - date_from)), 'MM_DD')) ) ; 
end loop;
 end; 
$func$;
```

Comment: To avoid leading space, use [`FM` prefix](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE) in the `to_char()` mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_union(date_from date, date_to date)
  RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE '
INSERT INTO dhcp.dhcp_map
SELECT * FROM dhcp.final_map_'
   || array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT to_char(date_from
                      + generate_series(0, (date_to - date_from)), 'MM_DD')), '
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM dhcp.final_map_'
   );
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT table_union('2012-12-01', '2013-01-10');
```

#### Major points

- Most important for performance: instead of one `INSERT` statement *per day* I generate and execute a *single* `INSERT` statement for everything. With `RETURNS text` and `RETURN` in place of `EXECUTE` you can see the generated statement:

  ```
  INSERT INTO dhcp.dhcp_map
  SELECT * FROM dhcp.final_map_12_01
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM dhcp.final_map_12_02
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM dhcp.final_map_12_03
  ...
  ```

  [->sqlfiddle for Postgres 8.3.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!10/f7764/1)
  As long as the amount of data to be inserted f9its into RAM, this is substantially faster.
- If your `INSERT` should be **huge** you may want stick with **one `INSERT` per day**.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_union_huge(date_from date, date_to date)
  RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
FOR i IN 0 .. (date_to - date_from)
LOOP
   EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO dhcp.dhcp_map
SELECT * FROM dhcp.final_map_'|| (date_from + i)::text;
END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

- Remove redundant parameter `$3` from function call. Replace with simple subtraction `$2 - $1`. Returns an integer (difference in days) in Postgres.
- Simplified `generate_series()` call.
- Replaced LOOP with [ARRAY constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) and [`array_to_string()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) to create a single statement.
- Largely simplified string handling. Just use the [pattern `MM_DD` with `to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) to extract your string from the date.

All Links to the manual of Postgres 8.3.

Comment: Thanks for such a great writeup.  I learn a ton from every one of your posts1 It turns out the insert statement I am applying is around a few billion rows so the union has been slower then the insert when written previously. I tried a variation of your code I added in the below comment but I am having problems getting it to work.

Comment: create or replace function table_union(date_from date, date_to date)
returns void language plpgsql as
$func$
declare 
day_1 date;
begin
    for day_1 in 
        select date_from + s.a as dates from generate_series(0, (date_to - date_from)) as s(a)
    loop
        execute 
        'insert into dhcp.dhcp_map select * from dhcp.final_map_'|| 
        array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT to_char(date_from
         + generate_series(0, (date_to - date_from)), 'MM_DD'))
         ) ;
    end loop;
end;
$func$;

Comment: @user7980: Better to put your updated version into the *question* (as opposed to comment), in a format easier to read. Or, if it's new enough, just open another question with it. I added a simple version for one INSERT at a time to my answer.